# Sum of multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

Keep getting error from the below code. I want to create few new columns where each column sum up every single column. Say column K (screen the whole column) gives a total amount in column M. Column L gives a total amount in column N etc.

```
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim T1 As Long
Dim T2 As Long

lastrow = dws("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)
T1 = worksheetfunction.Sum(range ("M2":lastrow))
Range("P2").Value = T1
T2 = worksheetfunction.Sum(range ("N2":lastrow))
Range("Q2").Value = T2
```

Comment: Try reading the information from the error message window first. Then, try do some search and correct errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the differences

```
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim T1 As Long
Dim T2 As Long

lastrow = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
T1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Summary").Range("M2:M" & lastrow))
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("P2").Value = T1 'Replace "Sheet2" with the name of your sheet
lastrow = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
T2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Summary").Range("N2:N" & lastrow))
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Q2").Value = T2 'Replace "Sheet2" with the name of your sheet
```

Comment: Thanks. I have replaced the "Sheet2" with "Summary". But the value did not show up in P2 nor Q2? no error message popped out. Tried to change the declare part from as Long to as Integer but still the same. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Do you have any values in M or N columns? It was working fine when I try it.

Comment: Yes. in the 1st workbook all the values were there then run the program will create a new workbook but the total value didnt show up.

Comment: This code will work only if both sheets are in the same workbook. Try to specify the workbook with Workbooks("Workbook name") before every worksheets("Sheet name")